# Pandas - convert float to int when there are NaN values in the column

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to convert float numbers to int in my df column with this one liner:

```
df['id'] = df['id'].map(lambda x: int(x))
```

But some values are NaN an will throw:

```
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: would `x.astype('int',errors = 'ignore')` work?

Comment: @rhug123 no, `nan` is still there and the column is cast to float automatically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`NaN` is itself float and can't be convert to usual `int`. You can use `pd.Int64Dtype()` for nullable integers:

```
# sample data:
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1, np.nan]})

df['id'] = df['id'].astype(pd.Int64Dtype())
```

Output:

```
     id
0     1
1  <NA>
```

Another option, is use `apply`, but then the `dtype` of the column will be `object` rather than numeric/int:

```
df['id'] = df['id'].apply(lambda x: x if np.isnan(x) else int(x))
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know about this. It looks like this was released in version `0.24.0` ( https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html ), so anyone with that version or later released on January 25, 2019 should be able to use this.